# How to iterate Map<string,List<string>> in vf page

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable

I have a map I am displaying in a `Visualforce Page` as below:

```
<apex:page controller="MyController">
    <apex:repeat value="{!str}" var="key">
           {!key}
           <apex:repeat value="{!mymap[key]}" var="value">
             {!value}
         </apex:repeat><br/>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class MyController {

public list<string> str{get;set;}
public MyController(){
 str = new list<string>{'Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'};
}

    public Map<String, List<String>> myMap {
        get {
            return new Map<String, List<String>>{
                    'Monday' => new List<String>{'123', '456','789'},
                    'Tuesday' => new List<String>{'654', '321'},
                    'Wednesday' => new List<String>{'654', '321'},
                    'Thursday' => new List<String>{'654', '321'},
                    'Friday' => new List<String>{'654', '321'},
                    'Saturday' => new List<String>{'654', '321'},
                    'Sunday' => new List<String>{'654', '321'}};

        }
    }
}
```

current ouptput:

```
Monday      456 123
Tuesday     456 123
Wednesday   456 123
Thursday    456 123
Friday      456 123
Saturday    456 123
```

Required Output:

```
Monday   Tuesday  Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday
456       456       234       234     123     123      123
123       123       456       456     234     678      890
```

Comment: you can refer an approach from my blog post http://santanuboral.blogspot.com/2017/02/display-records-with-rowspan-in.html

Comment: and/or you can also **[edit]** your post with your code and point out 'where' you are stuck, what is the behavior you expected and the one you currently have.

Comment: Please do not create duplicates of this question. If you would like to add information, **[edit]** it instead.

Comment: i checked your post but i unable to find in your post please help me out i posted my code

Answer (score 3):

This will work.. 
Replace your VF page with the below code It's working copy..
I have used html table..

```
<apex:page controller="MyController">
    <table>
        <apex:repeat value="{!str}" var="key1">
            <td>{!key1}</td> 
        </apex:repeat>
        <tr></tr>

        <apex:repeat value="{!str}" var="key">           
            <td>
                <apex:repeat value="{!mymap[key]}" var="value">
                    {!value} <br/> 
                </apex:repeat>
            </td>
        </apex:repeat>
    </table>
</apex:page>
```

Output looks like below snip:
[image]

Comment: Thanks alot This is working like a charm now i will build my logics on this...............Great Solution

Comment: Happy to hear that! Mark it as a solution so that others can refer it in case they encounter the same challenge. Glad I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `<apex:pageBlockTable>` here:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!daysOfWeek}" var="day">
    <apex:column headerValue="day" value="{!myMap[day]}" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Then in your controller, add this property:

```
public List<String> daysOfWeek
{
    get
    {
        return new List<String>
        {
            'Monday',
            'Tuesday',
            'Wednesday',
            'Thursday',
            'Friday',
            'Saturday',
            'Sunday'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: day
[123, 456, 789]
[654, 321]
[654, 321]
[654, 321]
[654, 321]
[654, 321]
[654, 321]

Comment: now i am getting outpout like this..