# Pass Map from Batch Apex to VisualForce email template and iterate on it

Tags: apex, visualforce, batch, email-template

I have a Batch Job called `ContractExpirationNotificationJob` and it identifies expiring contracts and sends the owners a list of expiring contract records by email.
Currently, I am using a method within the Batch class to be able to generate the email body in Html format.

- This method has a for loop to iterate over all contract records owned by a user, transforming them into a table.
- However, I aim to retrieve the email body from a template instead of generating it within the class. I believe, this approach would offer greater dynamism and control on ui.

During my research, I've realized that I can only integrate a for loop within a Classic VisualForce email template — a tool in which I lack experience entirely. Could anyone please provide answers to the following questions:

1. Is a VisualForce email template the only solution here if I want to utilize an email template in my scenario? If so, how can I pass my "Map<User, List> mapOwnerAndContracts" to the VF email template and iterate over it?
2. What would be any other alternatives to using an email template? Would it be advisable to keep it within the class as a method? (This approach does not seem appropriate to me since we would have no control over the template on the UI, and we would need to modify our code if a change is ever required in the template in the future.)

Please find below the batch class for the reference.
Thank you in advance.

```
public without sharing class ContractExpirationNotificationJob implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful
{
    
    Map<User, List<Contract>> mapOwnerAndContracts = new Map<User, List<Contract>>();

     // Identifiyig the expiring contract records in start method and Filling the map in execute method, owner as key and List of expiring contracts as values 

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext ctx) { 
        fflib_ISObjectUnitOfWork uowEmail = Application.UnitOfWork.newInstance(new List<SObjectType>{ EmailMessage.SObjectType });
        for(User owner : mapOwnerAndContracts.keySet()) {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            String[] toAddresses = new String[] { owner.Email };
            email.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
            email.setSubject('Contracts expiring soon');
            email.setHtmlBody(generateEmailBody(mapOwnerAndContracts.get(owner), owner));
            uowEmail.registerEmail(email);
        }  
        uowEmail.commitWork();
    }
    
    // Generates the HTML body for the email notification to be sent to contract owners
    // Prepares a list of contract records based on the owner by using a for loop
    private static String generateEmailBody(List<Contract> contracts, User owner) {
        String emailBody = '<html><body>';
        emailBody += '<p style="font-size: 14px;">Dear ' + owner.Name + ',</p>';
        emailBody += '<p style="font-size: 14px;">The contracts in the list below are set to expire soon. <br/>';
        emailBody += 'Your prompt action is necessary to ensure timely renewal or necessary actions are taken. </p>';
        emailBody += '<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">';
        emailBody += '<tr>';
        emailBody += '<th style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">Contract Number</th>';
        emailBody += '<th style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">End Date</th>';
        emailBody += '<th style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">Account Name</th>';
        emailBody += '<th style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">Account Owner</th>';
        emailBody += '<th style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">Customer Signed By</th>';
        emailBody += '<th style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">Company Signed By</th>';
        emailBody += '</tr>';
        for (Contract contract : contracts) {
            emailBody += '<tr>';
            emailBody += '<td style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;"><a href="' + 
                            URL.getOrgDomainURL().toExternalForm() + '/' + contract.Id + '">' + contract.ContractNumber +'</a></td>';
            emailBody += '<td style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">' + contract.EndDate + '</td>';
            emailBody += '<td style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">' + contract.Account.Name + '</td>';
            emailBody += '<td style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">' + contract.Account.Owner.Name + '</td>';
            emailBody += '<td style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">' + contract.CustomerSigned.Name + '</td>';
            emailBody += '<td style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">' + contract.CompanySigned.Name + '</td>';
            emailBody += '</tr>';
        }
        emailBody += '</table><p/>';
        emailBody += '</body></html>';
        return emailBody;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community. I'd suggest you use [edit] and reduce the scope of the code posted to only the relevant bits to get more response (so the community doesn't have to scroll so much and wade past unnecessary fluff) - see also [VF iterating over map](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/232060/how-to-iterate-mapstring-liststring-in-vf-page)